# mysql on windows, remote access

Tags: mysql, localhost, remote-access

I just downloaded and installed MySQL on a windows machine.  I will only be using it from the same machine. I would like to make sure that no remote connections can be made to my server.  What is the way I should do this? I am using windows. I disabled TCP/IP access altogether but it seems connections through pipes don't work (is this a windows thing?) Thanks.

Comment: Did you tried with Xming to access MySQL on remote computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your server listens to `127.0.0.1` ip instead of `0.0.0.0`

This can either be done by editing `my.ini`/`my.cnf` file or by editing the mysql service in windows.

Add following line to your `my.ini` file in `[mysqld]` section

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

See more on [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address)

Comment: yes, this is actually what i have been trying to do. where can i find the config file? when installing mysql i chose not to make it a service. thanks.

Comment: @Alex in your mysql installation directory. something like `C:\program files\mysql 5.0\ `

Comment: great, thank you! will this work if i have disabled the tcp/ip during configuration? i only let it listen to pipes. does this not work in windows? if so, how do i re-enable?

Comment: @Alex Pipe does not work on windows. The name of those pipe are actually *Unix Pipe*. If you do this no one can not access it.

Comment: a minus vote after such a long time? You must have strong reason.

Comment: @Alex I actually addressed the minus voter. I know its certainly not you. :D